# How Do You Flatten Terrain in A Uniform Fashion

Tags: mesh, modifiers, add-on, sculpting

I have a Blender file where I am trying to make the terrain flatter without causing huge divots and unnatural structures. So far the only thing I know how to do is select faces of the terrain, press `g` and move them downward on the y-axis but that just makes them look like huge mountain wedges into giant holes.

Here is an example:
[image]

I want to know if there is some sort of add-on or simple built-in functionality to gradually reduce the extremes of terrain topography.

Comment: You want to scale the geometry in a single axis.  Select the outside border, snap cursor to selection, set pivot point to cursor and orientation to global, s z move mouse confirm to scale constrained to global Z axis.

Comment: Probably also enable proportional editing while doing that.

Comment: You can also do this selectively by going into sculpt mode and using the flatten brush

Comment: @Nathan This fixed it perfectly! One more step, before you press `s` then `z` and move the mouse downwards, make sure you select at least 1 vertex and press `a` on the mouse to have all the vertices selected. Please make this into a answer so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to select all, just didn't say it.  Feel free to add your own answer and mark as solved; this has been dealt with innumerable times already here (not your fault, you don't know what to search for), so I'm not really eager for this to get any more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple. Select the outside border, snap the cursor to selection, set the pivot point to 3D cursor and set the orientation to global, make sure you select at least 1 vertex and press `a` on the mouse to have all the vertices selected press `s` then `z` and then move your mouse to scale to global Z axis.